# C - Segmentation Fault (core dumbed) with malloc()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have the following struct:

```
struct fibo_entry
{                          /* Definition of each table entry */
  int n;
  unsigned long long int lli;       /* 64-bit integer */
  char *str;
};
```

I am trying to print numbers and strings (number converted into a string) of X+1 number of Fibonacci passed by argument. And I am trying to create dynamically the space of `str` based in how many decimals I have on the actual number.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n;
  int i;
  struct fibo_entry *fibo_table;

  if (argc != 2)
    panic ("wrong parameters");

  n = atoi (argv[1]);
  if (n < 2)
    panic ("n too small");
  if (n > LIMIT)
    panic ("n too big");

    //Struct
    fibo_table = (struct fibo_entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct fibo_entry)*(n));
    //Fibonacci
    int var1 = 0;
    int var2 = 1;
    int aux = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
     fibo_table[i].lli = var1;
     if (var1 == 0){
        aux = 1;
     } else {
        aux = floor( log10( abs(var1)) + 1);
     }
     //When i use print no garbage chars...
     //printf("%d--> aux: %d var1: %d \n",i,aux,var1);
     //Generates the space of decimal we actually have on var1
     fibo_table[i].str = (char*)malloc(aux*sizeof(char));
     //Converts the number into string
     sprintf(fibo_table[i].str, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);
     aux = var1 + var2;
     var1 = var2;
     var2 = aux;
     fibo_table[i].n = i;
    }

  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
      printf ("%d %llu %s\n", fibo_table[i].n, fibo_table[i].lli,
              fibo_table[i].str);
    }

  free_memory(fibo_table, n);

 return 0;
}
```

Here I am trying to liberate the memory.

```
void free_memory(struct fibo_entry *table, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<size;i++){
        free(table[i].str);
    }
    free(table);
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 ��X�U
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 2 2
4 3 3
5 5 5
6 8 8
7 13 13
8 21 21
9 34 34
10 55 55
11 89 89
12 144 144
13 233 233
14 377 377
15 610 610
16 987 987
17 1597 1597
18 2584 2584
19 4181 4181
20 6765 6765
Segmentation fault (core dumbed)
```

The problem I have is I'm getting garbage chars on the `str = 0`, and I don't get why, when I do
`printf("%d--> aux: %d var1: %d \n",i,aux,var1);` I don't get the garbage chars. Why is that?
Also, I'm getting Segmentation fault because of `free()`. I've done some research but didn't found anything, I have already tried differents ways to free the memory:

```
free((*table)->str);
free(table[i]->str);
free(*(table+1)->str);
free(table[i].str);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do the `sprintf` first, and then `malloc` the `strlen` + 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There certainly may be other issues, but since you've only allocated space for `n` structs, you cannot loop with `for (i = 0; i<=n; i++)`.

You need to go one less than that with:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Attempting to access fibo_table[n] is undefined behavior.  The valid indices are 0 through n - 1.

Comment: My bad, I didn't specify that... the thing is that if the user writes 20 for example, I want 21 numbers of Fibonacci.

Comment: Well, then you'd better use `n + 1` in the call to `malloc`!

Comment: @AzmahQi, thanks is translated to an upvote and acceptance. Even without the edit, the comment also counts.